# extract non-nested list from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','b','c','d'],'y':[[1],[3,4],[2],[5]]})
```

I want to extract the list `[3,4]` so I did

```
df.loc[df.x=='b','y'].tolist()
```

but it returns a nested list.

```
[[3,4]]
```

How can I get a non-nested list from the dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `loc` expression returns a sequence rather than a scalar, you just need to select its first and only element:

```
df.loc[df.x=='b','y'].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can `explode` before

```
df1=df.explode('y')
df1.loc[df1.x=='b','y'].tolist()
... 
[3, 4]
```

Also simple fix

```
df.loc[df.x=='b','y']
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get a single cell value, try [`df.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html), it guarantees a single value:

```
df.at[pd.Index(df['x']).get_loc('b'), 'y']
# [3, 4]
```

This solution is guaranteed to fail if the key does not exist:

```
df.at[pd.Index(df['x']).get_loc('xyz'), 'y']
# KeyError: 'xyz'
```

The `pd.Index(df['x']).get_loc('b')` expression could also be replaced with `df['x'].eq(b).argmax()`, but be warned it will return an incorrect result if "b" does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try `loc` and `squeeze`

```
In [621]: df.loc[df.x=='b','y'].squeeze()
Out[621]: [3, 4]
```